# Можно ли как-то получить тип переменной, куда будет записанно значение функции?

Tags: c++, c++17

Существует некий класс, который хранит данные в `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::any>` и требуется реализовать некую функцию класса  `getVariable(const std::string &varName)`, чтобы она выводила тип для `std::any_cast` и для возвращаемого значения в зависимости от переменной, куда это значение будет присвоено, возможно ли это ? Например `int num = object.getVariable("score")` или `std::string str = object.getVariable("name")` Думаю над этим уже пару часов и схожусь на том, что такое сделать не получится.

Comment: мне кажется что не так что-то по дизайну. Возвращать всегда надо условный std::any или другой класс, а в этом классе уже определены нужны операторы преобразования. Как-то так https://ideone.com/PMg8Ig

Comment: Вам кажется, с дизайном все хорошо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самой функции этот тип узнать нельзя.

Можно вернуть из функции объект класса, с перегруженным оператором приведения типа:

```
template <typename T> operator T() {...}
```

Вместо `T` компилятор будет подставлять искомый тип.

Comment: Возник небольшой вопрос, возможно ли таким образом перегрузить оператор ()() ? Текущая моя попытка отказывается компилироваться :(
```template <typename variableType>
    variableType& operator()(const std::string & variableName){...}```

Comment: @Fqqlt Не, фокус работает только с оператором приведения типа. Из `operator()` нужно возвращать другой класс, для которого он перегружен.

Comment: Блин, жаль конечно, по моей задумке не получиться, придётся указывать тип данных, нужный мне, но всё равно спасибо за помощь, может ваш ответ поможет кому-то в подобной задаче :)

Comment: А можно посмотреть, как вы примените этот способ к конкретному `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::any>` из вопроса? а то я что-то не догоняю...

Comment: @Mikhailo https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-uAm_D

Comment: @HolyBlackCat То есть ваш класс Helper должен иметь все возможные приведения типов, которые могут встречаться в any?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat После примера вашего когда стало всё понятно, по итогу это как раз, что я искал, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Непосредственно так, как вы пишете - нет. Поставьте себя на место компилятора: ну вот откуда ему знать, что у вас под `"name"` прячется именно строка?

```
std::string str = object.getVariable("name");
```

Увы, это уж вы сами должны определить, что там у вас. Да и, кроме того, перегрузка функции возможна только по аргументам, но не по возвращаемому типу. Так что вам все равно пришлось бы писать что-то типа

```
std::string str = object.getVariable<std::string>("name");
```

А если вы все равно знаете, чего ожидать - то нечего и огород городить: все очень просто:

```
unordered_map<string,any> m;

int main()
{
    m["a"] = 1;
    m["b"] = "xaxa"s;

    string s = any_cast<string>(m["b"]);
    int i = any_cast<int>(m["a"]);

}
```

Вот только если вы все же напутаете... Будьте готовы перехватить исключение `std::bad_any_cast` в ситуации типа

```
    int i = any_cast<int>(m["b"]);
```

Comment: Я думал, может возможно подсказать компилятору, что перед = находится тот тип данных, к которому мне необходимо сделать каст :D

Comment: Вот вы и подсказываете - в `any_cast` :)